# iOS AES-128 encrypted streaming with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, encryption

I am developing an application for iPhone that will stream an encrypted video content. I was able to create an app that plays not encrypted stream using MPMoviePlayerController following the MPMoviePlayer class reference. That was really easy and simple.

I was searching through apple developer libraries, google and stack, but found nothing about encrypted streaming on iPhone or how to do it. I was wondering if the MPMoviePlayer does not have any methods to play such stream. Do I have to always download the .ts files, decrypt them and then somehow play them via MPMoviePlayer sequentially? Or is there anything that could simplify that process? I believe that the reason I didn't find it anywhere is that its really simple or I want to use a very inappropriate way to do it.

I was given a .m3u8 file where there are generated keyIDs and IVs. I suppose I need to implement some parser or something that will read them so I can use them, or is there also a simpler, better suited, method to do it?

Could anyone please direct me to use the right approach so I won't reinvent hot water?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of encryption are you using? Is it some in-house algorithm or 3rd party DRM encryption?

Comment: The server responds to my request with a AES-256 encrypted XML file and within it, there is the key that I will use to decrypt the .ts files with AES-128.

Comment: Another solution would be to decode the stream on the fly. For this you will need some kind of built-in HTTP server in your app. So your app would receive encrypted stream, decrypt it and stream again, but via built-in server. And MPMovePlayer will use this in-app server to play decrypted video.

Comment: Wouldn't that be even more complicated to create a server and within it implement the decryption of all the .ts files rather then decrypt all of them within the app? The main problem is that I dont know whether to download, decrypt, (somehow) put them on a queue for MPMoviePlayer to play, or another simpler know how?

Comment: Hi @kalafun
Did you succeed to read your encrypted .m3u8 file?
Do you have any answer to this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the project got dropped :-/

Comment: Google has provided an ExoPlayer for android but i have not found same anything for iOS. Please let me know if anyone found anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to support the key file reference in the M3U8 file? I succeeded to play encrypted video by doing so. The MPMoviePlayerController will download the key file and decrypt the media data for you, so you don't need to do anything.